# How to create setup when project included crystal reports and ms access connectivity in visual studio 2012?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

This is error in first form:

[image: This is error in first form]

This error in second form:

[image: This error in second form]

Comment: how to add any libraries like **.dll** file or other files and into the project... Above errors generate when the setup install into the another PC

Comment: Set the `Copy Local` property on the reference to `true`. You do this in Solution explorer -> Your Project -> References -> `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks ...` Then the dll should be included in your setup project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the crystal report engine dll or setup when using into the another pc...